# My PagerAdapter don't show anything

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

This pagerAdapter do't show anything, in my project I have another PagerAdapter (previously created) and that function perfectly, and it is like that. 
In fact I did ctrl+c and ctrl+v and I have changed the name of the reference classes.
PS.
The error isn't from `class Piatti` where I get a data from another class.

This is `Java class SlideAdapter_piatti`:

```
public class SlideAdapter_piatti extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public int[] images_carpi = {R.drawable.carpi_piatti_mostardafina, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_parmigiano, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_zamponecotechino};
    public String[] titolo_carpi = {"La Mostarda Fina", "Il Parmigiano Reggiano DOP", "Il Cotechino IGP e lo Zampone IGP"};
    public String[] descrizione_carpi = {
            "La Mostarda “fina” di Carpi, dalla lunga e complessa lavorazione, è una salsa dolce piccante utilizzata per accompagnare carni, soprattutto bollite come il lesso, il cotechino e lo zampone, o per accompagnare formaggi. Della mostarda Fina, però, non esiste un’unica ricetta autentica ma diverse ricette a seconda della famiglia che la produceva. Indubbiamente la coltivazione di mele e pere tipiche del territorio (come le mele Gagliardine e le Decime) favorì la creazione della ricetta, alle quali si aggiungevano bucce d’arancia, cedro candito, uvetta, senape, miele e varie spezie, ingredienti comuni a tutte le varie ricette di famiglia, oltre ad altri dettati da gusti personali o “ingredienti segreti”. La vera Mostarda Sopraffina di Carpi, però, era ricetta segreta della famiglia Sebellini che avevano una drogheria a Carpi. Chi la produce, la conserva, oggi come allora, in vasi di argilla a forma di pera rovesciata. La si prepara in inverno e, per questo, era uso farne dono per le feste natalizie.",
            "Il Parmigiano Reggiano DOP, prodotto tipico del territorio, nasce dal felice connubio tra lavoro umano e ingredienti locali. Tra questi il latte, reso speciale dai foraggi di cui si nutrono le mucche che lo producono, provenienti dai pascoli dell’Emilia e della Lombardia al di sotto del Po.",
            "Il cotechino IGP e lo zampone IGP sono due secondi piatti di largo consumo nella cucina modenese, soprattutto durante le festività natalizie. All'interno della pelle degli zampetti di maiale è insaccata la carne finemente tritata del maiale stesso. Di solito sono accompagnati con un contorno di lenticchie. Lo zampone nasce a Mirandola dove, narra la leggenda che durante il duro assedio di Papa Giulio II nel 1510-11, per poter meglio resistere alle difficoltà e per non lasciare al nemico animali così faticosamente ingrassati, un cuoco dei Pio pensò di tritare la carne dei maiali e di insaccarla nella pelle degli zampetti."};

    public int[] images_berlino = {R.drawable.carpi_piatti_mostardafina, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_parmigiano, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_zamponecotechino};
    public String[] titolo_berlino = {"", "", ""};
    public String[] descrizione_berlino = {"", "", ""};

    public int[] images_lubiana = {R.drawable.carpi_piatti_mostardafina, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_parmigiano, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_zamponecotechino};
    public String[] titolo_lubiana = {"", "", ""};
    public String[] descrizione_lubiana = {"", "", ""};

    public int[] images_trieste = {R.drawable.carpi_piatti_mostardafina, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_parmigiano, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_zamponecotechino};
    public String[] titolo_trieste = {"", "", ""};
    public String[] descrizione_trieste = {"", "", ""};

    public int[] images_norimberga = {R.drawable.carpi_piatti_mostardafina, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_parmigiano, R.drawable.carpi_piatti_zamponecotechino};
    public String[] titolo_norimberga = {"", "", ""};
    public String[] descrizione_norimberga = {"", "", ""};

    public SlideAdapter_piatti(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titolo_carpi.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(ScrollView)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ScrollView)object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_piatti, container, false);

        LinearLayout layoutslide = view.findViewById(R.id.slidelinear_piatti);

        Piatti p = new Piatti();
        p = (Piatti) view.getContext();
        String s = p.getIntent().getStringExtra("message4");

        ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.slideimg);
        TextView t1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        TextView t2 = view.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);

        switch (s){
            case "Carpi":
                img.setImageResource(images_carpi[position]);
                t1.setText(titolo_carpi[position]);
                t2.setText(descrizione_carpi[position]);
                break;
            case "Berlino":
                img.setImageResource(images_berlino[position]);
                t1.setText(titolo_berlino[position]);
                t2.setText(descrizione_berlino[position]);
                break;
            case "Lubiana":
                img.setImageResource(images_lubiana[position]);
                t1.setText(titolo_lubiana[position]);
                t2.setText(descrizione_lubiana[position]);
                break;
            case "Trieste":
                img.setImageResource(images_trieste[position]);
                t1.setText(titolo_trieste[position]);
                t2.setText(descrizione_trieste[position]);
                break;
            case "Norimberga":
                img.setImageResource(images_norimberga[position]);
                t1.setText(titolo_norimberga[position]);
                t2.setText(descrizione_norimberga[position]);
                break;
            default: break;
        }

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

}
```

This is "Java class Piatti":

```
public class Piatti extends AppCompatActivity {
    String s = "";
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SlideAdapter_piatti myadapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.piatti_layout);

        s = getIntent().getStringExtra("message4");

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_piatti);
        myadapter = new SlideAdapter_piatti(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }

    public void setS(String s){this.s=s;}
    public String getS(){return s;}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is `xml layout file, piatti_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.Piatti">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_piatti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</ScrollView>
```

This is `xml layout file, slide_piatti`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidelinear_piatti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttitle"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titolo esempio"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/slideimg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Descrizione piatto"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descrizione"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The code does not give me any error for this

Comment: ------ no idea?

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!, in `piatti_layout` there must be `LinearLayout` and not `ScrollView`.... I hate myself so much right now

Comment: Apologize for wasting time for those who want to solve the problem